# different colour schemas depends how file is opened

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, filetype-c++

this is my first steps in vim and I've started this from a config generated by vim-bootstrap service for neovim and c++ specific development. 
so I'm currently studying enabled plugins.

could someone explain me why there is a different colouring depends I'm opening c++ source from nerdtree panel or via usual :e

1. opening from :e - set filetype is cpp; fileformat is unix

   2. opening from nerdtree - filetype is cpp; fileformat is unix

so not difference in those values

[image]

[image]

here is a content of a config:

```
" vim-bootstrap 3340bde

"*****************************************************************************
"" Vim-PLug core
"*****************************************************************************
if has('vim_starting')
  set nocompatible               " Be iMproved
endif

let vimplug_exists=expand('~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim')

if !filereadable(vimplug_exists)
  if !executable("curl")
    echoerr "You have to install curl or first install vim-plug yourself!"
    execute "q!"
  endif
  echo "Installing Vim-Plug..."
  echo ""
  silent !\curl -fLo ~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  let g:not_finish_vimplug = "yes"

  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall
endif

" Required:
call plug#begin(expand('~/.config/nvim/plugged'))

"*****************************************************************************
"" Plug install packages
"*****************************************************************************
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'vim-scripts/grep.vim'
Plug 'vim-scripts/CSApprox'
Plug 'bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace'
Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
if isdirectory('/usr/local/opt/fzf')
  Plug '/usr/local/opt/fzf' | Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
else
  Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --bin' }
  Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
endif
let g:make = 'gmake'
if exists('make')
        let g:make = 'make'
endif
Plug 'Shougo/vimproc.vim', {'do': g:make}

"" Vim-Session
Plug 'xolox/vim-misc'
Plug 'xolox/vim-session'

if v:version >= 703
  Plug 'Shougo/vimshell.vim'
endif

if v:version >= 704
  "" Snippets
  Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
endif

Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'

"" Color
Plug 'tomasr/molokai'

"*****************************************************************************
"" Custom bundles
"*****************************************************************************

" c
Plug 'vim-scripts/c.vim', {'for': ['c', 'cpp']}
Plug 'ludwig/split-manpage.vim'


"*****************************************************************************
"*****************************************************************************

"" Include user's extra bundle
if filereadable(expand("~/.config/nvim/local_bundles.vim"))
  source ~/.config/nvim/local_bundles.vim
endif

call plug#end()

" Required:
filetype plugin indent on


"*****************************************************************************
"" Basic Setup
"*****************************************************************************"
"" Encoding
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=utf-8
set bomb
set binary


"" Fix backspace indent
set backspace=indent,eol,start

"" Tabs. May be overriten by autocmd rules
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

"" Map leader to ,
let mapleader=','

"" Enable hidden buffers
set hidden

"" Searching
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase

"" Directories for swp files
set nobackup
set noswapfile

set fileformats=unix,dos,mac
set showcmd

if exists('$SHELL')
    set shell=$SHELL
else
    set shell=/bin/sh
endif

" session management
let g:session_directory = "~/.config/nvim/session"
let g:session_autoload = "no"
let g:session_autosave = "no"
let g:session_command_aliases = 1

"*****************************************************************************
"" Visual Settings
"*****************************************************************************
syntax on
set ruler
set number

let no_buffers_menu=1
if !exists('g:not_finish_vimplug')
  colorscheme molokai
endif

set mousemodel=popup
set t_Co=256
set guioptions=egmrti
set gfn=Monospace\ 10

if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_mac") || has("gui_macvim")
    set guifont=Menlo:h12
    set transparency=7
  endif
else
  let g:CSApprox_loaded = 1

  " IndentLine
  let g:indentLine_enabled = 1
  let g:indentLine_concealcursor = 0
  let g:indentLine_char = '┆'
  let g:indentLine_faster = 1


endif



"" Disable the blinking cursor.
set gcr=a:blinkon0
set scrolloff=3

"" Status bar
set laststatus=2

"" Use modeline overrides
set modeline
set modelines=10

set title
set titleold="Terminal"
set titlestring=%F

set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w%=(%{&ff}/%Y)\ (line\ %l\/%L,\ col\ %c)\

" Search mappings: These will make it so that going to the next one in a
" search will center on the line it's found in.
nnoremap n nzzzv
nnoremap N Nzzzv

if exists("*fugitive#statusline")
  set statusline+=%{fugitive#statusline()}
endif

" vim-airline
let g:airline_theme = 'powerlineish'
let g:airline#extensions#syntastic#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#branch#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tagbar#enabled = 1
let g:airline_skip_empty_sections = 1

"*****************************************************************************
"" Abbreviations
"*****************************************************************************
"" no one is really happy until you have this shortcuts
cnoreabbrev W! w!
cnoreabbrev Q! q!
cnoreabbrev Qall! qall!
cnoreabbrev Wq wq
cnoreabbrev Wa wa
cnoreabbrev wQ wq
cnoreabbrev WQ wq
cnoreabbrev W w
cnoreabbrev Q q
cnoreabbrev Qall qall

"" NERDTree configuration
let g:NERDTreeChDirMode=2
let g:NERDTreeIgnore=['\.rbc$', '\~$', '\.pyc$', '\.db$', '\.sqlite$', '__pycache__']
let g:NERDTreeSortOrder=['^__\.py$', '\/$', '*', '\.swp$', '\.bak$', '\~$']
let g:NERDTreeShowBookmarks=1
let g:nerdtree_tabs_focus_on_files=1
let g:NERDTreeMapOpenInTabSilent = '<RightMouse>'
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 30
set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip,*.pyc,*.db,*.sqlite
nnoremap <silent> <F2> :NERDTreeFind<CR>
noremap <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" grep.vim
nnoremap <silent> <leader>f :Rgrep<CR>
let Grep_Default_Options = '-IR'
let Grep_Skip_Files = '*.log *.db'
let Grep_Skip_Dirs = '.git node_modules'

" vimshell.vim
let g:vimshell_user_prompt = 'fnamemodify(getcwd(), ":~")'
let g:vimshell_prompt =  '$ '

" terminal emulation
nnoremap <silent> <leader>sh :terminal<CR>

"*****************************************************************************
"" Functions
"*****************************************************************************
if !exists('*s:setupWrapping')
  function s:setupWrapping()
    set wrap
    set wm=2
    set textwidth=79
  endfunction
endif

"*****************************************************************************
"" Autocmd Rules
"*****************************************************************************
"" The PC is fast enough, do syntax highlight syncing from start unless 200 lines
augroup vimrc-sync-fromstart
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * :syntax sync maxlines=200
augroup END

"" Remember cursor position
augroup vimrc-remember-cursor-position
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
augroup END

"" txt
augroup vimrc-wrapping
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt call s:setupWrapping()
augroup END

"" make/cmake
augroup vimrc-make-cmake
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead CMakeLists.txt setlocal filetype=cmake
augroup END

set autoread

"*****************************************************************************
"" Mappings
"*****************************************************************************

"" Split
noremap <Leader>h :<C-u>split<CR>
noremap <Leader>v :<C-u>vsplit<CR>

"" Git
noremap <Leader>ga :Gwrite<CR>
noremap <Leader>gc :Gcommit<CR>
noremap <Leader>gsh :Gpush<CR>
noremap <Leader>gll :Gpull<CR>
noremap <Leader>gs :Gstatus<CR>
noremap <Leader>gb :Gblame<CR>
noremap <Leader>gd :Gvdiff<CR>
noremap <Leader>gr :Gremove<CR>

" session management
nnoremap <leader>so :OpenSession<Space>
nnoremap <leader>ss :SaveSession<Space>
nnoremap <leader>sd :DeleteSession<CR>
nnoremap <leader>sc :CloseSession<CR>

"" Tabs
nnoremap <Tab> gt
nnoremap <S-Tab> gT
nnoremap <silent> <S-t> :tabnew<CR>

"" Set working directory
nnoremap <leader>. :lcd %:p:h<CR>

"" Opens an edit command with the path of the currently edited file filled in
noremap <Leader>e :e <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . "/" <CR>

"" Opens a tab edit command with the path of the currently edited file filled
noremap <Leader>te :tabe <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . "/" <CR>

"" fzf.vim
set wildmode=list:longest,list:full
set wildignore+=*.o,*.obj,.git,*.rbc,*.pyc,__pycache__
let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND =  "find * -path '*/\.*' -prune -o -path 'node_modules/**' -prune -o -path 'target/**' -prune -o -path 'dist/**' -prune -o  -type f -print -o -type l -print 2> /dev/null"

" The Silver Searcher
if executable('ag')
  let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND = 'ag --hidden --ignore .git -g ""'
  set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor
endif

" ripgrep
if executable('rg')
  let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND = 'rg --files --hidden --follow --glob "!.git/*"'
  set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
  command! -bang -nargs=* Find call fzf#vim#grep('rg --column --line-number --no-heading --fixed-strings --ignore-case --hidden --follow --glob "!.git/*" --color "always" '.shellescape(<q-args>).'| tr -d "\017"', 1, <bang>0)
endif

cnoremap <C-P> <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . "/" <CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>b :Buffers<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>e :FZF -m<CR>

" snippets
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"

" syntastic
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list=1
let g:syntastic_error_symbol='✗'
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol='⚠'
let g:syntastic_style_error_symbol = '✗'
let g:syntastic_style_warning_symbol = '⚠'
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1
let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors = 1

" Tagbar
nmap <silent> <F4> :TagbarToggle<CR>
let g:tagbar_autofocus = 1

" Disable visualbell
set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=
if has('autocmd')
  autocmd GUIEnter * set visualbell t_vb=
endif

"" Copy/Paste/Cut
if has('unnamedplus')
  set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
endif

noremap YY "+y<CR>
noremap <leader>p "+gP<CR>
noremap XX "+x<CR>

if has('macunix')
  " pbcopy for OSX copy/paste
  vmap <C-x> :!pbcopy<CR>
  vmap <C-c> :w !pbcopy<CR><CR>
endif

"" Buffer nav
noremap <leader>z :bp<CR>
noremap <leader>q :bp<CR>
noremap <leader>x :bn<CR>
noremap <leader>w :bn<CR>

"" Close buffer
noremap <leader>c :bd<CR>

"" Clean search (highlight)
nnoremap <silent> <leader><space> :noh<cr>

"" Switching windows
noremap <C-j> <C-w>j
noremap <C-k> <C-w>k
noremap <C-l> <C-w>l
noremap <C-h> <C-w>h

"" Vmap for maintain Visual Mode after shifting > and <
vmap < <gv
vmap > >gv

"" Move visual block
vnoremap J :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap K :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv

"" Open current line on GitHub
nnoremap <Leader>o :.Gbrowse<CR>

"*****************************************************************************
"" Custom configs
"*****************************************************************************

" c
autocmd FileType c setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
autocmd FileType cpp setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab

" syntastic
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['python', 'flake8']

" vim-airline
let g:airline#extensions#virtualenv#enabled = 1

" Syntax highlight
" Default highlight is better than polyglot
let g:polyglot_disabled = ['python']
let python_highlight_all = 1


"*****************************************************************************
"*****************************************************************************

"" Include user's local vim config
if filereadable(expand("~/.config/nvim/local_init.vim"))
  source ~/.config/nvim/local_init.vim
endif

"*****************************************************************************
"" Convenience variables
"*****************************************************************************

" vim-airline
if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
  let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

if !exists('g:airline_powerline_fonts')
  let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_sep = ' '
  let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_alt_sep = '|'
  let g:airline_left_sep          = '▶'
  let g:airline_left_alt_sep      = '»'
  let g:airline_right_sep         = '◀'
  let g:airline_right_alt_sep     = '«'
  let g:airline#extensions#branch#prefix     = '⤴' "➔, ➥, ⎇
  let g:airline#extensions#readonly#symbol   = '⊘'
  let g:airline#extensions#linecolumn#prefix = '¶'
  let g:airline#extensions#paste#symbol      = 'ρ'
  let g:airline_symbols.linenr    = '␊'
  let g:airline_symbols.branch    = '⎇'
  let g:airline_symbols.paste     = 'ρ'
  let g:airline_symbols.paste     = 'Þ'
  let g:airline_symbols.paste     = '∥'
  let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'
else
  let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_sep = ''
  let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_alt_sep = ''

  " powerline symbols
  let g:airline_left_sep = ''
  let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
  let g:airline_right_sep = ''
  let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
  let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
  let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
  let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''
endif
```

Comment: What do `set filetype?` and `set fileformat?` say for each?

Comment: I'm using generated config (because just started to learn vim , just removed some unused plugins, and didn't add new values. seems I need to spend some time and try to configure manually?

Comment: I think you misunderstood @8bittree's question. They're asking what output  Vim gives if you type `:set filetype?` and `:set fileformat?` after opening the file via NERDTree and what the same commands report after opening the file via `:e`.

Comment: by the way - when I'm opening the file via :e after the opening from nerdtree, this will look okay, the same like via nerdtree

Comment: How about `:set spell?`

Comment: no spell file loaded, download it? in both cases

Comment: actually, this config doesn't look so important for me , I'm just looking for minimal c++ oriented config for quick work starting. if you are experienced in vim , could you recommend me a plugins for the requirements. let me describe these ones, only 6 are there

Comment: Place the cursor on one of the words (e.g. friend) that is highlighted differently, and type `:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name")`. What is reported for the two different methods of opening the file?

Comment: okay, let me check

Comment: cStatement, in both cases. used "return" keyword which is really displayed differently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59681/discussion-between-rich-and-amigo421).

Comment: Voted to close because in chat @amigo421 told me he can no longer reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

As far I can tell from the images there was no change in the colorscheme (which you change using the [`:colorscheme`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_06.txt.html#06%2e3) command). What you are seeing is probably a change on the syntax highlight and maybe different [`'fileformat'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fileformat%27), as the MS-Windows line endings (`^M`) are displayed and highlighted in one of the images.

In any case, I'd stay away from config generated by tools, such as vim-bootstrap service, as explained in this question about [VIM and SPF13 Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325442/vim-and-spf13-configuration). The problem you are facing probably comes from the interaction of plugins and/or configurations, and I believe that you'd be far better using a simpler configuration and fewer plugins, which would make it far easier to debug problems as the one you found.

To check which plugin or setting that you are using is causing the problem you could follow the procedure described on [Vim-FAQ  2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5).